# SQL Server 2008 R2 login issue from jdbc

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I've installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows 2008 R2 Enterprise x64. I've written a small jUnit test that simply connects to the database using a SQL server login account. On a fresh start up of the OS, I can authenticate once and thus the jUnit test passes.

Subsequent jUnit tests fail though. When I use SQL Server Profiler to see what is going on during the subsequent tests I see 20 login and logout audits. After the 20, the jUnit test throws the following details.

Anyone experience this behavior before?

```
driverErrorCode: 3

cause: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.

SQLState: 08S01
```

Answer (score 2):

I was running Java 6u29.

Guess what?! There's a **BIG FAT** bug. The bug prevents Java from connecting to a SQL Server instance.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7106332

I backed out to Java6u26 and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple of things that may be causing this:

1) SQL Server is limited to 20 concurrent connections

2) The jdbc driver maxActive parameter is set to 20.

In both of these cases, I suspect the issue may be that the active connection that you open in the test is not closed.